# Checking if View (Button) is disabled

Tags: android, button, view

I have this `Button`:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="false" />
```

If user clicks on it while it is disabled, I want to throw a `Toast`.  But this does not work:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

        Button b = (Button) v;
        if (b.isEnabled()) {


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Please Select a Student",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would try to do it with a toggle button. You can click it, but give it different states. Like on/off instead of enabled/disabled.

Comment: Where is the `id` for your button?

Comment: @Naddy  edited out to simplify things

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Views will not receive the `onClick` callback when disabled. You should add a check for whether a student is selected or not inside of your button click logic rather than disabling the button.

Comment: Well that answers that.  I will try that way instead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a disabled `Button` can not listen to any event, but you can customize your own `Button` by extending `Button` class to make your own definition of disabling.

Answer (score 0):

When the Button is disabled you can not listen events. Use states in ImageButton creating a selector to make more visual the differences between enable and disabled status.When the Button is disabled you can not listen events. Use states or use ImageButton with selector file to put dif